# Python program for Jump game II

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, programming-challenge, comparative-review

This is a [Leetcode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/jump-game-ii/):

> *Given an array of non-negative integers, you are* *initially positioned at the first index of the array.*
>
> *Each element in the array represents your maximum jump length at that*
>   *position.*
>
> *Your goal is to reach the last index in the minimum number of jumps.*
>
> ***Note:***
>
> *You can assume that you can always reach the last index.*

Here is my first solution to this problem:

```
def jump(nums):
    n = len(nums)
    curr_far = min(nums[0], n - 1)
    next_far = 0
    step = 0
    for i in range(n):
        if i <= curr_far:
            if next_far < i + nums[i]:
                next_far = min(i + nums[i], n - 1)
            if i == curr_far and curr_far != 0:
                curr_far = next_far
                step += 1

    return step

nums = #Enter a list.       
print(jump(nums))
```

Here is an example of an input/output:

```
nums = [2,3,1,1,4]
>>> 2
```

The minimum number of jumps to reach the last index is `2`.

Jump 1 step from index `0` to `1`, then `3` steps to the last index.

Here is my second solution to this problem:

```
class Solution:

    def __init__(self, nums):
        self.nums = nums

    def jump(self, nums):
        if not nums or len(nums) == 1:
            return 0

        curr = 0
        count = 0
        while(curr < len(nums)):
            maxReach = -1
            index = 0
            for i in range(1, nums[curr] + 1):
                if curr + i >= len(nums) - 1:
                    return count + 1
                else:
                    if nums[curr + i] + i > maxReach:
                        maxReach = nums[curr + i] + i
                        index = curr + i
            curr = index
            count += 1

nums = #Enter a list.           
game = Solution(nums)
print(game.jump(nums))
```

Input/output - Same as above.

So, I would like to have a code review for the efficiency of both the programs.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Umm... Why the downvote? Is anything wrong with the question?

Comment: I didn't downvote but I'm tempted to... a short description about each solution like why you have implemented it that way would be great. Do you think any of them is better, prettier etc... what were the reasons you've decided to take either of the approaches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Improving the first solution

I like the first solution better, because I find it easier to understand how it works, and it's shorter.

It can be a bit simpler. The condition `if i <= curr_far:` is unnecessary and can be safely dropped.

Instead of iterating over a range of indexes, I nice trick is to use `enumerate`, like this:

```
for index, value in enumerate(nums):
```

This way, instead of `nums[index]` in the loop body, you can use `value` directly.

Another code smell is the condition `if i == curr_far and curr_far != 0` executed in every iteration of the loop, even though `curr_far != 0` will only be false for the first iteration, otherwise always true.

I didn't like most of the variable names...

- Instead of `step`, I would find `jumps` more natural
- Instead of `curr_far` and `next_far`, I would find `reach` and `next_reach` more intuitive

All in all, I would write like this instead:

```
class Solution(object):
    def jump(self, nums):
        end = len(nums) - 1
        if not end:
            return 0

        reach = 0
        next_reach = 0
        jumps = 0
        for pos, value in enumerate(nums):
            if next_reach < pos + value:
                next_reach = pos + value
                if next_reach >= end:
                    return jumps + 1

            if pos == reach:
                reach = next_reach
                jumps += 1
```

#### Issues with the second solution

- Looks more complex than the first, and I think unnecessarily so
- The `__init__` method is completely unnecessary
- The outer parentheses are unnecessary in `while(curr < len(nums)):`
- The convention for the naming style of variables in Python is `snake_case` instead of `camelCase`

Answer (score 2):

This problem lends itself to a recursive solution. You want a recursive algorithm that

- returns `0` if the length of the input array `nums` is `1`
- otherwise creates a new input array for a jump of size from `1` to `nums[0]`, calculates the jumps for the new input array, adds 1, and returns the minimum

In Python this would be:

```
def jump(nums):
    if len(nums)<=1:
        return 0
    else:
        return min(1+jump(nums[m:]) for m in range(1,min(len(nums),nums[0]+1)))
```